# Vue DOM image won't show correctly

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I'm using the Vue framework and creating an image using the `DomUtil.Create` function. In this image I want to dynamically write the source to this image. But the image won't show to the user.

I put a normal image on the page using the `<img>` tag and it works here. Only when creating the DOM element it doesn't work. I put the path hard coded in here so it is certain that the path is correct.

```
var img = L.DomUtil.create("img", "popUpImg", divImg);
img.src = '@/assets/pictures/1.png';
```

Comment: [Vue Loader: Asset URL Handling](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/asset-url.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use `require()`

When binding to a project path / filename, use `require`:

```js
require('@/assets/pictures/1.png');
```

If you use project asset paths and filenames in Vue CLI, Webpack actually renames them while bundling. Vue CLI quietly takes care of this if you use a string path for `img src` *in the template*.  But in any other situation, you need to manually use Webpack's `require` to give the correct path and filename at runtime.

<sup>- **Note:** You can `npm run build` and then check the `dist` > `img` folder to see the renaming for yourself. -</sup>

---

## Can I use a variable with `require()`?

When using a variable path/filename, `require` needs some assistance. You must hard code at least the first portion of the path as a string.

- For example, this works:

```js
const filename = '1.png';
require('@/assets/pictures/' + filename); // <-- The string is needed
```

- This works too:

```
const path = 'assets/pictures/1.png';
require('@/' + path); // <-- This is good enough too
```

- But this would ***not*** work:

```js
const fullpath = '@/assets/pictures/1.png';
require(fullpath); // <-- No. Can't infer the path from a variable only
```

Read more in the [Vue Loader](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/asset-url.html) docs

Comment: Thanks this worked! I have a small follow up question. If I implemented require(picturepath) I will get a warning that the request of a dependency is an expression. So how do I implemented a variable into the require function?

Comment: You're welcome- To make matters just a little more complicated, `require` needs some help with that path, and can't infer it straight from a variable.  Put only the image name in the variable and do this:  `require('@/assets/pictures/' + yourImgVariable)`